# Failed Publish when subscribed to same topic as publisher?

Tags: c, embedded, messaging, mqtt, mosquitto

I am currently working on a embedded c project using mqtt 3.1.1 and mosquitto broker 1.4.3.  the issue I have is when the client board is publishing and subscribed to the same topic, after a random number of messages the client is blocked and the connection gets timed-out.

I am trying to send a string message, 25 bytes, over 3G network. Using QOS2 on both pub & sub, I have tried different settings on the client for keepalive (15s <-> 120s) and have a delay between each message (2000ms <-> 300000ms), on the broker I have tried different settings also, but nothing seem to work, is it possible to send messages using QOS2 over a 3G network or am I expecting too much?

We want to guarantee the transfer of some data that is critical so if this is not possible on mqtt is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

A keepalive of 120ms sounds bogus.

Keepalive is there for the broker to detect that a client may have gone missing, without having to wait for the TCP connection to time out. You would typically use a keepalive in the range of seconds, if not minutes.

With a keepalive of 120ms, you have to send a PING packet at least every 100ms or so (or do any other MQTT exchange in that time frame), so it might explain why you are introducing so much latency in your scenario – and probably killing your 3G data plan too ;-)

I suggest you start using a keep-alive of 30s to see if that improves things.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I am currently using ka=120s, the client works fine once it is publishing only or subscribing only.  The issue is when the client is pub and sub on the same topic.

Comment: Are both your clients by any chance using the same client ID? That could be the problem...

Comment: Yes it is a single client that is publishing and subscribing to the same topic, is that the issue.  Maybe it just cant be done on a single client?